# Integrating Ember.js client side code with our server side code in RESTAPI

Tags: ember.js

Requirement : To develop an application (with CRUD operations) which uses JAVA REST API along with hibernate as server side technology and Ember.js for developing UI as our client side technology.

Technology to be used :
•   RESTAPI and hibernate (Server side)
•   Ember.js (Client side)
•   PostgreSQL (Database)

According to our findings on Internet , I have created an application using Ember.js (using Ember cli tool) and it is working fine. Application developed is using Ember’s MVC architecture.

Issue Faced : Integrating Ember.js client side code with our server side code (already developed in REST WS with hibernate).

On doing some analysis on Internet and going through some of the Ember.js tutorials I am not able to get a starting approach for this integration.

So please guide me on the integration  (JAVA REST API with Ember.js) or even a help in developing a sample application with this configuration will very much useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add some more information on how your JAVA REST API looks like? For example, a "typical" request and it's response?

Answer (score 1):

While developing your whole application, one of your achitectural design point should be about your clint-server communication. How will your client communicate with your server? What will your requests look like? Will your requests only send a piece of data to save/update or a whole complex domain entity to do a specific thing? What will your ***verbs*** look like?

You can read more about [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html). With `ember.js` you can implement any level of it. (The model is from 2010, maybe you can find more up-to-date knowledge.) IMO, `ember-data` fits so well with level 3. So you should also check whether `ember-data` is suitable for you or not? If it is suitable for you, you may need to do some little modifications in your serializers etc. But if it is not suitable for you, you can have a look other addons to make rest calls. Such as [`ember-ajax`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax).

For our case, we have `ember.js` at front-end, java/rest/hibernate at back-end. Our rest apis are more like Richardson's level 1 or level 2 samples. But not level 3. We are sending specific DTO's to specific urls. We are not using `ember-data`. We have a service that handles remote connection. All our routes are using that service. The service is so simple as it covers [`jquery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).